# React-Native-Camera not working on IOS but working on Android, IOS application crashes

Tags: react-native-ios, react-native-camera

I am new to react-native, I worked with different work-arounds but got fail nothing gone to work, when I use react native camera in my application it perfectly works on Android device or simulator but when it comes to IOS application crashes, many posts said that is because of info.plist and I added the permissions there as well by going to: ios/myproject/info.plist via myproject.xcworkspace I added the below information, the permissions works correctly when I allow my application by pressing OK it suddenly crashes with no error and when I try to reopen it, it is not able to open on IOS, simulator as well as on device.
In some examples I got the text on the screen Camera is not Authorized, while some crashes it thoroughly.

note: when it take permissions from me and I allow the permissions the application crashes in IOS only, and in some cases it gives a string on the screen by saying "camera is not authorised".
I hope somebody help me

This is the info.plist

[image: this is my info.plist]

set my paths as in the pod file:
[image]

Comment: Have you run 'pod install' in the iOS folder of the project?

Comment: yes, I run the pod install as well.